# Magento : Attributes For Product Not Saving

Tags: magento-1.9, database, admin, attributes

I am using Magento 1.9.x.
I have created some attributes for products,
When I save, this attribute not working.

Pls help me
https://ibb.co/hUmVY9

Thanks

Comment: Have you check magento log file? Is there any error?

Comment: I've got this in log file 2018-08-19T18:13:04+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 31  in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Flat.php on line 833        https://ibb.co/nnBFSp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I have found the issue is in the DB, I have checked the system attribute and the all have the "backend_type" as varchar while the custom or the new attributes I have uploaded through MAGMI were with a backend_type static. 
https://ibb.co/hL2yhp

Just update the **backend_type** from **static** to **varchar** and it should save in the backend.